# Take i'th element of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list :

```
{{j1,j2,j3},{j4,j5,j6}}
```

I would like to take the 5'th element of this list that is composed of two sublist.

How to do that ?

Indeed `j[[5]]` returns an error as it thinks I want the 5'th sublist which doesn't exist.

I tried to find a similar topic but I didn't find it on this website.

I am a huge beginner in mathematica

Comment: `Flatten[list][[5]]`?

Comment: Thank you but is there a more compact way to do it ? Because it would force me to create another variable if I want a compact expression. I am computing a sum and it would complexify the reading of it if I write Flatten[...]. And I would like to prevent multiple variable creations. But I am probably asking too much :o

Comment: I don't know what you mean by creating another variable...What about `Flatten[j][[5]]`?  We basically have three symbols here, `Flatten`, `j` or `list`, and `5`, which is just only symbol more complicated than `j[[5]]`, which doesn't work.  You could use `j[[2, 2]` to get `j5`, but that does not really fit how you have framed the problem.

Comment: Well ok it seems it is the only solution. What I meant is that I could write b=Flatten[j] And then use b[[5]] which is compact.

Comment: No, one can also do `list[[2,2]]`, that is, the second element of the second sublist.

Comment: Do you want to define a function `b[i_] := Flatten[j][[i]]` and then `b[5]`?

Comment: If you are looking for an equivalent of Matlab's indexing (where an n-dimensional array can be indexed by a single value, which treats the underlying array as a vector with Matlab's array ordering) you won't find an exact equivalent in Mathematica. Also, your comments about 'compact'-ness are somewhat odd for Mathematica: Mathematica is mostly an immutable functional language, so statements like `Flatten[x][[i]]` are quite common. It would be a mistake to assume that `Flatten[x][[i]]` is fundamentally slower than Matlab's `x(i)` --- it could be, but that depends on both implementations.

Comment: Ok thank you. I was more thinking about lisibility of big expression that on performance but I think you get what was disturbing me.

Answer (score 3):

In:

```
xss = {{j1, j2, j3}, {j4, j5, j6}};
{m, n} = QuotientRemainder[5, 3];
xss[[m + 1]][[n]]
```

Out:

```
j5
```

Deeper? Tensor?

In:

```
{u, v, w} = {3, 4, 5};
xss = Array[Subscript[x, {#1, #2, #3}] &, {u, v, w}];
Clear[f, m, n, o];
f[m_, n_, o_] := (m - 1) v w + (n - 1) w + o
xss /. Subscript[x, {m_, n_, o_}] -> {f[m, n, o], 
    Subscript[x, {m, n, o}]} // MatrixForm
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

In:

```
Clear[f, x, m, n, o, rules];
SeedRandom[1]
{u, v, w} = {3, 4, 5};
xss = Array[Subscript[x, {#1, #2, #3}] &, {u, v, w}];
f[m_, n_, o_] := (m - 1) v w + (n - 1) w + o
rules = MapIndexed[Rule[f[Sequence @@ #2], #2] &, xss, {3}]  // Flatten

{m, n, o} = 6 /. rules
xss[[m]][[n]][[o]]
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

{1, 2, 1}

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can you generalize this to deeper arrays?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard probably ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the list is fixed you could make a lookup table of positions to extract:

```
L = {{j1, j2, j3}, {j4, j5, j6}};
lookup = Position[L, _, {Length[Dimensions[L]]}, Heads -> False];
part[x_] := Extract[L, lookup[[x]]]

part[{2, 3, 6}]
```

> {j2, j3, j6}